# JS: Is that possible to show empty browser status line, for each event on the page

Tags: javascript

I have an application that send very big quantity of requests to the server (they appears after the page is loaded, and made from flash app)
This happens so often that status line go mad (displaying: Transferring data text every few seconds), and it's really annoying.

I that possible to handle all events on the page, and don't allow them to change status line? Or set it to empty string, if it's impossible to disable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many UAs the user can disable the "feature" of changing the status line with JavaScript so the short answer to your question is:

No, at least not reliable.

A not reliable semi solution could be that you launch your webapp in a new window without a status bar. But again, not reliable as users can override that or have new windows open as tabs etc.

Possibly OT: personally I think the user has the right to know when her/his UA is sending and/or receiving data. It´s about integrity, privacy and all that stuff.

Just try to embrace the fact that the end user (the actual owner of the UA) is in control (and should be).